# The title from theme options is not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show dynamic title that means user can add his own title from theme options, but it's not going up. My theme options page is working fine and even my title is showing up in the options page ... while unable to show on page.

Here is mine code for theme options.

```
<!-- Option 2: Custom Heading for banner -->
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Heading for page banner' ); ?></th>
    <td>
        <input id="theme_settings[heading]" type="text" size="36" name="theme_settings[heading]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['heading'] ); ?>" />
        <label for="theme_settings[heading]"><?php _e( 'Enter your desired title here' ); ?></label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It shows a good title like shown below in image theme options page!

Now the problem is that once I use code in my main page it never shows up, while its saved in WordPress as shown in red rectangle in above image.

Here is the code I am using in my main page, that code is being used in 2 pages, index.php and frontpage.php:

```
<?php if($options['heading']) { ?>
    <h1><?php echo $options['heading']; ?></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1>a fresh start for the family</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Can any one point out the mistake?

Image removed as I could not upload ... simply means that my theme options allow me to add title in backend and even saved that title but now my page still shows that static title.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve it with the `get_option` function, like `echo get_option('heading');` (the name - `heading` - being the name you gave to the option when you saved it to the database)

Comment: Yes, I was missing that part to get data from database options, I was simply using that value without getting that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not getting your value from database then you can use get_option to simply fetch your value and then you can proceed.

Here is the example code snippet:

```
<p><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( __( 'Character set: %s', 'textdomain' ), get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) ); ?></p>
```

Here is the full WordPress get_option page reference URL ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/

Comment: Thanks for your help and time ... I have gotten my values and will be checking that URL for future use as well ...